# Can't stream PDF file (.net core 2.0)

Tags: asp.net-core

For a few days I have no idea how to solve my problem.

I need return to user PDF document dynamically generated based on ID. I use for this NReco.PdfGenerator.LT. When I running a project directly from VS2017 everything works fine and the file is downloaded. But if I publish a project on an IIS server and then try clicking on the button, will open a page that does not exist (HTTP ERROR 404).

**Button:**

```
<a asp-controller="Dokumenty" asp-action="PobierzPotwierdzenieDokPdf" asp-route-DokID="@item.Dok_DokID" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" title="Drukuj PDF"></i></a>
```

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<FileResult> PobierzPotwierdzenieDokPdf(int DokID)
    {

        var dokument = _context.Dokumenty.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Dok_DokID == DokID);
        var notatki = _context.DokumentyNotatki.Where(d => d.DokNot_DokID == DokID);

        viewDokumentPotwierdzeniePdf viewDokumentPotwierdzeniePdf = new viewDokumentPotwierdzeniePdf()
        {
            Dokument = dokument,
            DokumentNotatka = notatki
        };

        var htmlContent = await _viewRenderService.RenderToStringAsync("Dokumenty/DokumentPotwierdzeniePdf", viewDokumentPotwierdzeniePdf);

        var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter
        {
            PageHeight = 210,
            PageWidth = 148,
            Margins = new PageMargins() { Bottom = 5, Left = 5, Right = 5, Top = 5 },
            Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape,
            PageFooterHtml = "<div style='font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; color: grey;'>Strona <span class='page'></span> z <span class='topage'></span> | Operator drukujący: " + HttpContext.Session.GetString("Ope_Nazwisko") + " | Data wydruku: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " | <b>System ERP Polimer</b></div>"
        };
        htmlToPdf.License.SetLicenseKey("PDF_Generator_Bin_Examples_Pack_0000000000", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        htmlToPdf.PdfToolPath = @"C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\";

        byte[] pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent);

        FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdfBytes, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = dokument.Dok_NrKancelaryjny.Replace("/", "_") + ".pdf"
        };

        dokument.Dok_Wydruk = 1;
        _context.Entry(dokument).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return fileResult;
    }
```

IIS is trying to open the url http://domainname.int/Dokumenty/PobierzPotwierdzenieDokPdf?DokID=77 where the number at the end is the ID. But that page does not physically exist.

Please help. What am I doing wrong?
P.S. sorry for my English :)

Comment: Nobody has any idea?

Comment: I guess "page doesn't exist" means that you get 404/Not Found, and it seems this is deployment configuration problem. Have you tried to add one more controller method that returns some trivial result (say, some string) and check if you able to access it on production server?